# Путь к properties файлам для setBundle JSTL

Tags: java, maven, jsp, jstl, properties

Есть maven web-проект. Пытаюсь на странице JSP через JSTL установить ResourceBundle для локализации.
JSTL тег для установки.

```
    <fmt:setBundle basename="loc" var="lang"/>
```

Вопрос! Куда я должен в maven проекте положить properties файлы чтобы смог до них добраться через basename "loc"???

Comment: До этого надо разобраться что такое эти файлы и как они используются. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/838017/204920) есть ответ.

Comment: @RomanC Спасибо! Заработало. Положил properties файлы в resources. Только вот не нашел ни где информации по этому. Может быть посоветуете где почитать?